# SSL certificate returned for multiple server blocks

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx configuration with multiple virtual hosts and subdomains. Each subdomain needs to have a different SSL certificate bound. Here is the configuration for my first subdomain:

```
server {
listen 443;
server_name a.website.com;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/a/a.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/a/a.rsa;
.....
```

The configuration for my second:

```
    server {
    listen 443;
            listen 3443;
            server_name b.website.com;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/b/b.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/b/b.key;    
....
```

The problem is if I go to b.website.com, the SSL certificate for both a.website.com and b.website.com are returned when I expect only b.website.com to be bound. I validated this using ssllabs.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you checked your `b.crt` that it only contains the domain name for your other domain, and not for both domains?

Comment: Actually that makes sense. I bundled it directly from godaddy but I figured out the issue. The second cert was only returned if SNI isn't enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice that in ssllabs the second certificate was only returned if SNI wasn't enabled which makes sense because both certs are on the same IP. Apparently the integration we're working with doesn't support SNI (crazy I know) so I guess I have to spin up another server.